# Need to separate time from string

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to remove all text before a time that looks like either 8am or 8:00am based on what a user will type in. It could be any time for the front including pm.

Here is what I am looking for:

```
$appointment = "9th annual fundraiser - 8:30 am - 3 pm"
```

It can also look like:

```
$appointment = "9th annual fundraiser - (8:30 am - 3 pm)"
```

or

```
$appointment = "9th annual fundraiser - (event 8:30 am - 3 pm)"
```

or

```
$appointment = "9th annual fundraiser 8:30 am - 3:00 pm"
```

What I use for most other applications is the following:

```
$appointment -creplace '^[^1-9]*'
```

but it doesn't work in this case and I have looked for a good answer by using ?'s and everything else and I am not understanding it.

My goal is to make it so that it skips over the first number in this case (could be 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc.) and have it pull the time out. So that `$appointment` will look like:

8:30 am - 3 pm

I have tried using these formulas and I can't seem to tell it to pull out the 
times that will *usually* be X:XX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on this regex: `\d+(:\d+)?\s+[ap]m`

RegEx explanation:

1. `\d+` : One or more digit
2. `(:\d+)?` : Colon followed by one or more
   digits. One or zero of this combination. This how it works for 3:00
   AM as well as 3 AM.
3. `\s+` : One or more space (between 3:00 and AM). Make it `\s*` to make space optional.
4. `[ap]m`  : am OR pm

Solution 1

```
$regex = "\d+(:\d+)?\s+[ap]m"
$matches = ($appointment | Select-String $regex -AllMatches).Matches.Value
$matches -join " - "
```

Solution 2

```
$regex = "\d+(:\d+)?\s+[ap]m"
$regex = $regex + "\s*[-]\s*" + $regex
$matches = ($appointment | Select-String $regex -AllMatches).Matches.Value
$matches
```

If you're sure your input contains 2 times, I prefer Solution 1 because it's independent of whatever is in between the times. So it works for things like "3 pm to 6 pm" as well.

Comment: Nice! I knew a guru with regex would come along. So much simpler than my answer

Comment: Believe me, hardly a guru :P I was in the middle of posting an answer involving `.split()` a couple of regex passes through the tokens, when I realized my 25 lines function could be reduced to this regex.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing this! The output I get doesn't have the "8:30 am - 3 pm". The output I got was : 
```
8:30 am
3 pm
```

Comment: Updated to give the - as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using regex's:

```
Function Get-StringTime()
{
    # Set up a results ArrayList
    $results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    
    $regexs = @(
        # See https://regexr.com/ and you can drop
        # these expressions into the bar up top and
        # the Tools section at the bottom will explain
        # each expression
        
        [regex]"\b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b", # matches 8:00am-3:00pm
        [regex]"\b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b",       # matches 8am-3pm
        [regex]"\b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b", # matches 8:00am-3pm
        [regex]"\b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b"  # matches 8am-3:00pm
    )

    # Setup sample data, 1 for each match
    $a1 = '9th annual fundraiser - (8am - 3pm)'
    $a2 = '9th annual fundraiser - (8am - 3:00pm)'
    $a3 = '9th annual fundraiser - (8:00am - 3pm)'
    $a4 = '9th annual fundraiser - (8:00am - 3:00pm)'
    $a5 = '9th annual fundraiser - (13:00pm - 1:00am)'
    $arrs = @($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5)

    foreach($appointment in $arrs)
    {
        # strip out all the spaces so we can use less regexs

        $newAppointment = $appointment.Replace(' ','')

        Write-Host "`nAppointment data: " -NoNewline
        Write-Host $newAppointment -ForegroundColor Magenta

        # check this against each regex

        foreach($regex in $regexs)
        {
            Write-Host "Trying regex: " -NoNewline
            <#
                To show the user the regex being used
                we need to convert to a string, otherwise
                it will return an object type of RegEx
                which default outputs like this:

                Options MatchTimeout      RightToLeft
                ------- ------------      -----------
                   None -00:00:00.0010000       False
            #>

            Write-Host $($regex.ToString()) -ForegroundColor Yellow

            if($regex.Match($newAppointment).Value -ne '')
            {
                Write-Host "Match found | " -NoNewline  -ForegroundColor Green
                Write-Host "Item: $($arrs.IndexOf($appointment)) | Regex match Index: $($regexs.IndexOf($regex))"

                $results.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
                                                TimeString=$regex.Match($newAppointment).Value;
                                                AppointmentIndex=$($arrs.IndexOf($appointment));
                                                MatchingRegex=$regex.ToString();
                                                MatchingRegexIndex=$regexs.IndexOf($regex);
                }) | Out-Null
            }
            else { 
                Out-Null 
            }
        }
    }

    return $results
}

Get-StringTime
```

Output returns (with colorization in a PS console):

```
Appointment data: 9thannualfundraiser-(8am-3pm)
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Match found | Item: 0 | Regex match Index: 1
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b

Appointment data: 9thannualfundraiser-(8am-3:00pm)
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b
Match found | Item: 1 | Regex match Index: 3

Appointment data: 9thannualfundraiser-(8:00am-3pm)
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Match found | Item: 2 | Regex match Index: 2
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b

Appointment data: 9thannualfundraiser-(8:00am-3:00pm)
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b
Match found | Item: 3 | Regex match Index: 0
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b

Appointment data: 9thannualfundraiser-(13:00pm-1:00am)
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b
Trying regex: \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b

TimeString    AppointmentIndex MatchingRegex                             MatchingRegexIndex
----------    ---------------- -------------                             ------------------
8am-3pm                      0 \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b                              1
8am-3:00pm                   1 \b\d{1}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b                        3
8:00am-3pm                   2 \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}(am|pm)\b                        2
8:00am-3:00pm                3 \b\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)-\d{1}:\d{2}(am|pm)\b                  0
```

Hopefully this gives you something to hack through. If you wanted to make it more re-usable, you could add a parameter in the function call like:

```
Function Get-StringTime([String]$AppointmentText){...}
```

and call it in a PS prompt or a script that loads this function (either hard coded in, or *maybe* better from an imported module):

```
$someVariable = Get-StringTime -AppointmentText '9th annual fundraiser - (8am - 3pm)'
Write-Output $someVariable
```

That would require cutting out the hardcoded examples I added to represent some possible scenarios, `$a1` through `$a5`, and changing `$arrs` to `$arrs = @($AppointmentText)` or other ways, up to what you prefer.

Note that this does not account for military-style time, XX:XX or permutations where there are 2 digits before the `:` in the time string.